# How do you create an array of flags in a string? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

So if I have a string like this: `hello there --flag test --anotherFlag`

How can I get an array of the flags (--something) in that statement and then also get a string not including those flags? Also please note that the flags don't take any values, so I would want --flag, not --flag test

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some string and array methods that make this task easy.

```js
const command = 'hello there --flag test --anotherFlag';

const words = command.split(' ');
console.log(words); // [ 'hello', 'there', '--flag', 'test', '--anotherFlag' ]

const flags = words.filter(word => word.startsWith('--'));
console.log(flags); // [ '--flag', '--anotherFlag' ]

const notFlags = words.filter(word => !word.startsWith('--'));
console.log(notFlags); // [ 'hello', 'there', 'test' ]

const stringOfNotFlags = notFlags.join(' ');
console.log(stringOfNotFlags); // ''hello there test'
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Regular Expressions

```js
const text = "hello there --flag test --anotherFlag";
const result = [...text.matchAll(/--[a-zA-Z]*/g)]; // matches all letteres preceded with --
console.log(result) // array of Regex matched words
```